# How do I make this template specialization with variadic arguments a friend of a class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-specialization, friend-function

I have the following builder function:

```
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    Wrapper(T);
};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
inline Wrapper<T>
buildWrapper(Args&&... args) noexcept { 
  return Wrapper<T>(T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

I want to make this the only thing that can create an instance of the following class, so I've made the ctor private and attempted to mark the above template function as a friend.

```
class Bar {
private:
  Bar(bool);
  friend inline Wrapper<Bar> buildWrapper<Bar>(bool) noexcept;
}
```

But this generates an error:

```
error: no function template matches function template specialization 'buildWrapper'
note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'type-parameter-0-1 &&' against 'bool'
```

I've tried some reasonable looking variations, but I'm just not sure what the correct syntax here to declare the template specialization as a friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with this declaration:

```
friend inline Wrapper<Bar> buildWrapper<Bar>(bool) noexcept;
```

1. You can't use the `inline` specifier here.
2. There is no such specialization of `buildWrapper` that takes a `bool` argument. Your function template takes forwarding references, so it would always take some kind of reference to `bool`.

The correct spelling is:

```
friend Wrapper<Bar> buildWrapper<Bar>(bool&&) noexcept;
```

Although you probably would then have to additionally friend the other kinds of `bool` parameters, which gets unwieldy quickly. Easier to just friend all of 'em:

```
template <typename T, typename... Args>
friend Wrapper<T> buildWrapper(Args&&...) noexcept;
```

There's no such concept of "conditional friendship" that would let you just friend the `Bar` ones (e.g. you can't add constraints here to just limit to the `Bar`s).

Comment: Ah, yeah, the inline was something I added in desperation.  This builds, I will now test it.  Thank you!